# Java could not open/create prefs error

Tags: java

I am trying to get MIDI audio to play, but when ever I do this it keeps returning the error `

```
May 18, 2014 10:23:29 AM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 
         0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
```

I have gone into `regedit` and my permissions are on `EVERYONE`, but it just doesn't want to work.

CODE

```
import javax.sound.midi.Instrument;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiChannel;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.midi.Synthesizer;

public class Sound {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws MidiUnavailableException {
        int channel = 0;
        int volume = 80;
        int duration = 200;

        Synthesizer synth;
        synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
        synth.open();
        MidiChannel[] channels = synth.getChannels();
        channels[channel].noteOn(60, volume); // C note
        synth.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428098/groovy-shell-warning-could-not-open-create-prefs-root-node

Comment: Tried that but when creating a new key it returns `cannot create key`

Comment: May not it be an insufficient rights problem? Have you tried to create the key as an administrator?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it, I realized that I was just going to the menu and selecting `new`. I didn't actually go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft`

Answer (score 11):

I was faced this issue on Windows 10 64-bit and was able to resolve the problem by manually creating the following registry key.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs
```

Hope this helps for the Windows users.

Comment: Work for me, thanks.
More details, just **right click on "JavaSoft" - "New" -"Key", and rename the key to "Prefs"**.  
Re-run the gradle task, the warning message is gone.

Answer (score 8):

It's a known Java bug, still around on Windows 10 and update 112. Just run the program once from an elevated command prompt and it goes away.

Answer (score 6):

It's a very well known Windows problem. [Just try it](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/LQfsBSwD_ug):

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft.....Right click the icon, then change the permission to full operation

Answer (score 2):

It's java problem

I've try to solve using only USER_PREFERENCES, but the WindowsPreferences class has this code

```
static final Preferences userRoot = new WindowsPreferences(USER_ROOT_NATIVE_HANDLE, WINDOWS_ROOT_PATH);

static final Preferences systemRoot = new windowsPreferences(SYSTEM_ROOT_NATIVE_HANDLE, WINDOWS_ROOT_PATH);
```

So it try to read systemPreferences yes or yes.

I've try changing priviledges on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE but now in win-10 it doesn't works. In the past, in win-7 it worked.
It does not important, it's only a trace if you use USER_PREFS

This is my (tricky) solution... write this code in the main method or before using Preferences

```
static {
    PlatformLogger logger = PlatformLogger.getLogger("java.util.prefs");
    logger.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution, it only make the WARNING log disappear and shouldn't be used.