# Antlr Parse tree view on windows

Tags: windows, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to view antlr4 parse tree on Windows. I followed the instructions on https://www.antlr.org/ I setup the antlr4 path and grun path also added the CLASSPATH. The grun command with "-tree" works but when I specify "-gui" it freezes in the cmd.

[image: ScreenShot]

I tried fixing that error message by following instruction on [Java could not open/create prefs error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720446/java-could-not-open-create-prefs-error) and it went away but I still can't see the parse tree.

Comment: Use the right tools for the job: Visual Studio Code and this ANTLR4 extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mike-lischke.vscode-antlr4

Comment: I am using this instead. Thank you

Comment: Complete guess - can you start the command window using Run as administrator and retry?  Looks like the s/w is trying to set som prefs in registry and failing at that.

Comment: I tried it. Did not work either

Answer (score 1):

I don't have this problem on Windows 10. I am using Java SE 13 and ANTLR 4.8. I followed the section "Generate and compile the parser" on this [blog](https://bobthecod.blogspot.com/2020/02/antlr-with-python-3-example-parsing.html) to set up properly on Windows 10. The blog uses Git Bash and Windows 10.