# An error keeps coming up when using repast simulator

Tags: java, compiler-errors, runtime-error, simulator, repast-simphony

I looked at the demos and built my own zombie simulator as described in the documentation, but an error keeps coming up and I'm pretty sure its not to do with my code since I just copied it from the docs for the zombie simulator and opened the demos repast provides.

when I run the simulator it gives me this error

---

2014/10/03 16:05:19,354: Scenario Load Error
repast.simphony.scenario.ScenarioLoadException: ParseError at [row,col]:[5,21]
Message: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "type".
    at repast.simphony.scenario.ScenarioLoader.load(ScenarioLoader.java:220)
    at repast.simphony.ui.RSApplication.open(RSApplication.java:353)
    at repast.simphony.ui.RSAppConfigurator.postWindowOpen(RSAppConfigurator.java:39)
    at saf.core.ui.GUICreatorDelegate.runDisplay(GUICreatorDelegate.java:188)
    at saf.core.ui.GUICreator$1.run(GUICreator.java:18)
    at simphony.util.ThreadUtilities$Runner.run(ThreadUtilities.java:33)
    at simphony.util.ThreadUtilities.runInEventThread(ThreadUtilities.java:47)
    at saf.core.ui.GUICreator.runDisplay(GUICreator.java:16)
    at repast.simphony.ui.RSUIPlugin$1.run(RSUIPlugin.java:104)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[5,21]
Message: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "type".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.nextEvent(Unknown Source)
    at repast.simphony.scenario.data.ContextFileReader.read(ContextFileReader.java:40)
    at repast.simphony.scenario.ScenarioLoader.load(ScenarioLoader.java:126)

### ... 22 more

Also on the eclipse console it gives me this error before repast starts

---

Oct 03, 2014 4:05:01 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences

### WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.

I just can't figure out what is going on but I need to solve the problem soon because I need to work with repast for a uni project.

Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

The first error is not a coding error but a parsing error - it is likely a typo in your context.xml file (the error message indicates line 5, column 21).  Did you edit it as advised on pages 18-20 of the repast getting started guide?  Without seeing your context.xml file, I can't say exactly what the error is in it - if you want to add the first 5 lines of it then we can probably diagnose.

The second message (warning, not error) on the console window is common and is not associated with the first error.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428098/groovy-shell-warning-could-not-open-create-prefs-root-node) might help if you want to get rid of it - however I have not experienced any problems with leaving it there.