# Saving User Settings Inside a JAR

Tags: java, jar

I've created an application that is going to be run on Windows, Mac OX and Linux. I need to be able to store and read user settings on the fly.

User settings take the form of strings and a key and value pair would work well.

I'm currently using a properties file however this can't be written too on the fly within a JAR.

I'm struggling to find alternatives, what are the options to be able to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the properties file in the user home directory using `System.getProperty("user.home")` assuming the security manager, if any, allows it. Using properties files to save preferences allows editing the preferences from outside the application.

Another option is to use the [Java preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/index.html) for a transparent and platform-independent way of persisting the preferences.

Comment: I get the following error using Java preferences API : WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.

Comment: I also get a java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to save a file to "user.home".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428098/groovy-shell-warning-could-not-open-create-prefs-root-node may help.

Comment: Under MacOS, the preferred location for configuration files is `~/Library/Application Support/{app name}`, under windows it's `~\AppData\Local\{app name}` or `~\AppData\Roaming\{app name}` depending on your needs

Comment: @JackTrowbridge The error would suggest that you do not have adequate security permissions to write to the registry...