# Error While building Windows Phone 8 environment on a IBM Worklight 7.0 project

Tags: windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst

While building Windows Phone 8 environment on a IBM Worklight 7.0 project it shows some errors in the console.

> Console Output

- Starting build process: application 'myapp', environment 'windowsphone8'
- Application 'myapp' with environment 'windowsphone8' build finished.
- Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.

Is this a major issue ?
Any solutions to fix this one ?
After this error i opened the project on Visual Studio.

Comment: Where do you see this? Visual Studio or Eclipse? It is not clear from your question.

Comment: I face this issue in Eclipse.

Comment: Do you have full root permissions in the developer machine?

Comment: Yes i have root permission.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428098/groovy-shell-warning-could-not-open-create-prefs-root-node

Comment: If you've found an answer - write it as an answer and not a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer from this link.
[[Groovy Shell warning "Could not open/create prefs root node ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428098/groovy-shell-warning-could-not-open-create-prefs-root-node][1])
As per the steps described, i did and it and is working fine.

- Go into your Start Menu and type regedit into the search field.
- Navigate to the following path
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft
- Right click on the JavaSoft folder and click on New -> Key
- Name the new Key Prefs and everything should work.