# Can't compile GWT app using 2.8.0-SNAPSHOT and Java 8 with gwt-maven-plugin

Tags: gwt, java-8, gwtp, gwt-maven-plugin, gwt-2.8

I am struggling to get my app to compile using GWT 2.8.0-SNAPSHOT and [Mojo's gwt-maven-plugin 2.8.0-SNAPSHOT](https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/)

I receive the same compiler errors each time:

```
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.8.0-SNAPSHOT:compile (default) @ UsavAppV7 ---
[ERROR] Jul 20, 2016 9:34:23 AM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
[ERROR] WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
[INFO] Compiling module com.utilitiessavings.usavappv7.Project
[INFO]    [ERROR] An internal compiler exception occurred
[INFO] com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Unexpected error during visit.
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.translateException(JVisitor.java:111)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:276)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:118)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JDeclarationStatement.traverse(JDeclarationStatement.java:49)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContext.traverse(JModVisitor.java:88)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemove(JModVisitor.java:331)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:92)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:139)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:135)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody.traverse(JMethodBody.java:83)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.visitChildren(JMethod.java:785)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.traverse(JMethod.java:777)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.mainLoop(UnifyAst.java:1379)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.exec(UnifyAst.java:875)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.unifyJavaAst(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1410)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.constructJavaAst(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1222)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1140)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:255)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:255)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:202)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:143)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:204)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:155)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:144)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:118)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:125)
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl.setUserData(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/w3c/dom/UserDataHandler;)Ljava/lang/Object;
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.W3cDocumentBuilder.startElement(W3cDocumentBuilder.java:127)
[INFO]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:392)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.W3cDomHelper.documentFor(W3cDomHelper.java:74)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator.getW3cDoc(UiBinderGenerator.java:208)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator.generateOnce(UiBinderGenerator.java:183)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator.generate(UiBinderGenerator.java:128)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.core.ext.IncrementalGenerator.generateNonIncrementally(IncrementalGenerator.java:40)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:745)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:103)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:78)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:262)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:251)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.PrecompilationContextCreator$1.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(PrecompilationContextCreator.java:86)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.createStaticRebindExpression(UnifyAst.java:493)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.createRebindExpression(UnifyAst.java:463)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.handleMagicMethodCall(UnifyAst.java:588)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.endVisit(UnifyAst.java:293)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall.traverse(JMethodCall.java:268)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  ... 35 more
[INFO]       [ERROR] at com_gwtplatform_mvp_client_DesktopGinjector_DesktopGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java(132): GWT.create(ApplicationView$Binder.class)
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall
[INFO]       [ERROR] at com_gwtplatform_mvp_client_DesktopGinjector_DesktopGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java(132): Object created = GWT.create(ApplicationView$Binder.class)
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JDeclarationStatement
[INFO]       [ERROR] at com_gwtplatform_mvp_client_DesktopGinjector_DesktopGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java(131): {
[INFO]   Object created = GWT.create(ApplicationView$Binder.class);
[INFO]   assert created instanceof ApplicationView$Binder;
[INFO]   ApplicationView$Binder result = (ApplicationView$Binder) created;
[INFO]   this.memberInject_Key$type$com$utilitiessavings$usavappv7$client$application$ApplicationView$Binder$_annotation$$none$$(result);
[INFO]   return result;
[INFO] }
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock
[INFO]       [ERROR] at com_gwtplatform_mvp_client_DesktopGinjector_DesktopGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java(131): {
[INFO]   Object created = GWT.create(ApplicationView$Binder.class);
[INFO]   assert created instanceof ApplicationView$Binder;
[INFO]   ApplicationView$Binder result = (ApplicationView$Binder) created;
[INFO]   this.memberInject_Key$type$com$utilitiessavings$usavappv7$client$application$ApplicationView$Binder$_annotation$$none$$(result);
[INFO]   return result;
[INFO] }
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody
[INFO]       [ERROR] at com_gwtplatform_mvp_client_DesktopGinjector_DesktopGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java(131): com.utilitiessavings.usavappv7.client.application.com_gwtplatform_mvp_client_DesktopGinjector_DesktopGinjectorGinjector_fragment.get_Key$type$com$utilitiessavings$usavappv7$client$application$ApplicationView$Binder$_annotation$$none$$()Lcom/utilitiessavings/usavappv7/client/application/ApplicationView$Binder;
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:38 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-20T09:34:52+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 65M/534M
```

I don't know whether this is a problem with Java 8, GWT, or GWTP.

Any advice on how to investigate further or what could be causing it would be appreciated.

#### Edit:

pom.xml (snippets)

```
<properties>
    <!-- client -->
    <gwt.version>2.8.0-SNAPSHOT</gwt.version>
    <gwtp.version>1.5.1</gwtp.version>
    <gin.version>2.1.2</gin.version>

    <gwtbootstrap3.version>0.9.3</gwtbootstrap3.version>
    <gwtbootstrap3-extras.version>0.9.2</gwtbootstrap3-extras.version>

    <gwt-log.version>3.3.2</gwt-log.version>

    <!-- server -->
    <gae.version>1.9.38</gae.version>
    <guice.version>4.1.0</guice.version>
    <objectify.version>5.1.13</objectify.version>

    <persistence-api.version>1.0.2</persistence-api.version>
    <servlet-api.version>2.5</servlet-api.version>
    <javax.validation.version>1.0.0.GA</javax.validation.version>
    <hibernate-validator.version>4.1.0.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.9</slf4j.version>
    <jackson.version>2.7.0-rc2</jackson.version>

    <guava-version>20.0-SNAPSHOT</guava-version>

    <!-- testing -->
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <jukito.version>1.4.1</jukito.version>
    <cucumber.version>1.2.4</cucumber.version>

    <!-- maven -->
    <gwt-maven-plugin.version>2.8.0-SNAPSHOT</gwt-maven-plugin.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.18.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.3</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-resources-plugin.version>2.5</maven-resources-plugin.version>
    <maven-processor-plugin.version>2.0.5</maven-processor-plugin.version>
    <maven-build-helper-plugin.version>1.10</maven-build-helper-plugin.version>

    <target.jdk>1.8</target.jdk>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>

    <gae.home>${settings.localRepository}/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/${gae.version}</gae.home>
    <mvn.gae.home>
        ${settings.localRepository}/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/${gae.version}/appengine-java-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-${gae.version}
    </mvn.gae.home>

</properties>

<build>

    <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/super</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/apt</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/gwt</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                        <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${target.jdk}</source>
                <target>${target.jdk}</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <proc>none</proc>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- GWT -->
        <!-- 'mvn gwt:run' - runs development mode -->
        <!-- 'mvn gwt:debug' - runs debug mode -->
        <!-- 'mvn gwt:compile' - compiles gwt -->
        <!-- 'mvn integration-test' - runs the gwt tests (*GwtTest.java) -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt-maven-plugin.version}</version>

            <configuration>
                <strict>true</strict>
                <testTimeOut>180</testTimeOut>
                <mode>htmlunit</mode>
                <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
                <style>PRETTY</style>

                <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
                <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
                <server>com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher</server>
                <appEngineVersion>${gae.version}</appEngineVersion>
                <extraJvmArgs>-Ddatastore.default_high_rep_job_policy_unapplied_job_pct=20 -Xmx2g -Dappengine.sdk.root=${mvn.gae.home}
                </extraJvmArgs>
                <port>8888</port>
                <incremental>false</incremental>
                <bindAddress>0.0.0.0</bindAddress>
                <runTarget>Project.html</runTarget>
                <modules>
                    <module>com.utilitiessavings.usavappv7.Project</module>
                </modules>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>gcloud-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <verbosity>info</verbosity>
                <runtime>java</runtime>
            </configuration>
            <version>2.0.9.106.v20160420</version>
        </plugin>
```

#### Libraries

- Java 1.8.0_92
- Maven 3.3.9
- GWT 2.8.0-SNAPSHOT
- GWTP 1.5.1
- Guava 20.0-SNAPSHOT
- Guice 4.1.0
- Gin 2.1.2

Comment: Based on the *java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl.setUserData(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/w3c/dom/UserDataHandler;)Ljava/lang/Object;* line I would guess that one of the snapshots is pulling in an incompatible version of xerces.  Can you update with the version of xerces that is on the classpath in each case?

Comment: Pass -X to Maven and check the classpath in the log. FWIW, I used SNAPSHOT with UiBinder and net.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin and it works, so at least it's not a bug in GWT.

Comment: Found the culprit! It was this lib: https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader. It has a dependency on xercesImpl 2.4.0 (from 2006). I added a dependency to 2.11.0 and it compiles fine. Thanks guys!

Comment: PR here: https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader/pull/45

Comment: You should add your comment on the fix as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading [my own comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38457973/cant-compile-gwt-app-using-2-8-0-snapshot-and-java-8-with-gwt-maven-plugin#comment64403696_38457973) to an answer.

I discovered the library [excel-streaming-reader](https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader) had a dependency on xercesImpl 2.4.0 (from 2006).

I declared an additional dependency to 2.11.0 to solve the issue:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have notified the owner of the problem. Github issue: https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader/issues/44

Answer (score 0):

*Updated answer*. As question author found out based on comments, the problem was with incompatible Xerces library that was pulled by excel-streaming-reader.

To resolve similar issues, passing -X to Maven to examine all libraries used during compilation and turning on logging via logLevel property in `maven-compiler-plugin` helps to narrow down the problems like this.

In my original answer I also recommended to manually create 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Prefs` on 64bit WinPC.
You can find additional details e.g. in this post [how to create Prefs root node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428098/groovy-shell-warning-could-not-open-create-prefs-root-node)

GWT tries to access Windows registry to store or retrieve encryption key data via `java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences`. This warning is annoying, but mostly harmless, you can skip this part unless you like your logs clean.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not the issue. I can confirm I receive that warning too, but it works in my case. I dunno what might be wrong though.

Comment: I agree with @SriHarshaChilakapati - I have always had that warning but it never seems to be an issue.

Comment: Yes, commenters are correct. I did create the registry path to get rid of warning for myself, but the error is `InternalCompilerException`, which is unrelated.

Comment: Gave you an upvote as it seems this is a useful answer for people facing the `Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs` error :)

Comment: Are you related to Makka Pakka by any chance? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=makka+pakka&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1680&bih=925&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF44-J05jOAhXHKsAKHSXzAoMQ_AUIBygC&dpr=1