# MIDI program warning

Tags: java, midi

I am running a MIDI program given in Head First Java in code kitchen section "First Music Video" program is running but there is warning

```
WARNING:Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefsat root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
```

can anyone explain what is this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to create a registry key `HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs` (or `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Prefs` in W10) for it to work.

see this post:

[Groovy Shell warning "Could not open/create prefs root node ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428098/groovy-shell-warning-could-not-open-create-prefs-root-node)