# Suppressing Java Preferences Systemroot Warning

Tags: java, console, preferences

How do I suppress the warning printed to the console by the following piece of code:

```
Preferences systemRoot = Preferences.systemRoot();
```

The warning is as follows (or similar):

```
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
```

Note:
I want to just ignore this warning by not printing anything to the console instead and [not manually create a registry key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15698789/3764804) or [running the application as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33406783/3764804).

Here is the method responsible for the warning:

```
private  WindowsPreferences(int rootNativeHandle, byte[] rootDirectory) {
        super(null, "");
        int[] result =
                WindowsRegCreateKeyEx1(rootNativeHandle, rootDirectory);
        if (result[ERROR_CODE] != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            logger().warning("Could not open/create prefs root node " +
                    byteArrayToString(windowsAbsolutePath()) +
                    " at root 0x" + Integer.toHexString(rootNativeHandle()) +
                    ". Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code " +
                    result[ERROR_CODE] + ".");
            isBackingStoreAvailable = false;
            return;
        }
        // Check if a new node
        newNode = (result[DISPOSITION] == REG_CREATED_NEW_KEY);
        closeKey(result[NATIVE_HANDLE]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it :)

```
PlatformLogger platformLogger = PlatformLogger.getLogger("java.util.prefs");
platformLogger.setLevel(PlatformLogger.Level.OFF);
```

Alternatively [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3363747/3764804).